# how to use scrapifier gem for url fetching and gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. I want to fetch url, image, title and price from e commerce sites How to Use this scrapify gem. Could you please eloborate it.

It was a bit confusing in documentation given in https://github.com/tiagopog/scrapifier

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be confused of with its usage.You just need to pass the **`required url`** of the website as a **`string`**.For example

```
'http://adtangerine.com'.scrapify
#=> {
#   title:       "AdTangerine | Advertising Platform for Social Media",
#   description: "AdTangerine is an advertising platform that uses the tangerine as a virtual currency for advertisers and publishers in order to share content on social networks.",
#   images:      ["http://adtangerine.com/assets/logo_adt_og.png", "http://adtangerine.com/assets/logo_adt_og.png", "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/adtangerine-prod/users/avatars/000/000/834/thumb/275747_1118382211_1929809351_n.jpg", "http://adtangerine.com/assets/foobar.gif"],
#   uri:         "http://adtangerine.com"
# }
```

And also as it there in the documentation,you can **`choose`** which url you want it to be **`scraped`** like this

```
'http://adtangerine.com and www.twitflink.com'.scrapify(which: 1)
#=> {
#   title:       "TwitFlink | Find a link!",
#   description: "TwitFlink is a very simple searching tool that allows people to find out links tweeted by any user from Twitter.",
#   images:      ["http://www.twitflink.com//assets/tf_logo.png", "http://twitflink.com/assets/tf_logo.png"],
#   uri:         "http://www.twitflink.com"
# }

'http://adtangerine.com and www.twitflink.com'.scrapify(which: 0)
#=> {
#   title:       "AdTangerine | Advertising Platform for Social Media",
#   description: "AdTangerine is an advertising platform that uses the tangerine as a virtual currency for advertisers and publishers in order to share content on social networks.",
#   images:      ["http://adtangerine.com/assets/foobar.gif"],
#   uri:         "http://adtangerine.com"
# }
```

**Note:** The Examples are copied from its Documentation.

Comment: Installed scrapifier gem and tried to run a simple program But i got error as  gem `<main>': undefined method `scrapify' for #<String:0x007faeee234570> (NoMethodError)

Comment: `<main>': undefined method `scrapify' for #<String:0x007faeee234570> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @user3710415 I mean on which line you ar getting that error? Post that line

Comment: 'http://www.jabong.com/Sangria-Half-Jaquard-Half-Embroidered-Anarkali-Kurta-393198.html!'.scrapify

Comment: @user3710415 You given it like this only `'jabong.com'.scrapify` right?

Comment: 'jabong.com/Puma-Black-Sports-Backpack-356509.html'.scrapify
The line itself showing error at scrapify

Comment: @user3710415 Just give like this `'jabong.com'.scrapify`

Comment: It dosen't worked..
I want to fetch image, price and title of the product from the url

Answer (score 0):

Do This 
`gem install scrapifier`

Then Over Irb console Do These

```
require 'scrapifier'
```

OutPut should be

```
 => true
```

Then

```
'http://adtangerine.com and www.twitflink.com'.scrapify(which: 0)
```

OutPut should be

```
 => {:uri=>"http://adtangerine.com", :title=>"AdTangerine | We're experiencing problems with our servers.", :description=>"Hey there! Our web app will be back very soon, hold on just a little bit more :-)", :images=>[]}
```

Simple Enough!!

- You Are Doing `require 'scrapify'` Or Not ?

Comment: yes i did..
code got executed but i din't get any output as shown by u.

Comment: Can you Share You code sample Exactly? need to know what you are doing wrong ?

Comment: got it. explicitly defined to view output.
Can i know how to fetch the particular image from site (all images are of same type .jpg)

Comment: `wget url` will download that image to system.
Or
you can show that image url directly to views without download. make sense ?

its a small issue cannot take much time i think 

Try to take help over IRC OR ChatClient Via Talking with others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to test.Sample code.The URL has to be valid else use condition

```
require 'open-uri' # already part of your ruby install
require 'scrapifier'

puts 'Wow! What an awesome site: http://petspinboard.com'.scrapify
```